# flexisel failure

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to execute a slideshow in  my php file. this slideshow have a scripts to link at in the heading and a js function that gioes at the bottom before the  tag.
I have searched all around still cannot do it..
here is the slide..

```
******<!--please note that I am trying to insert this slideshow in a php file    
   on my local server.and therew Are other html elemets in the page alerady.-->******


<head>
  <link href="css/adstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="source/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<ul id="sliderx" > 
   <li><img src="images/image.png" /></li>
   <li><img src="images/image.png" /></li> 
   <li><img src="images/image.png" /></li>                                                                          
</ul>
```

and here is the js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
    $("#sliderx").flexisel({
    visibleItems: 1,
    itemsToScroll: 100,
    infinite: true,
    navigationTargetSelector: null,
    autoPlay: {
        enable: true,
        interval: 500,
        pauseOnHover: true
    },

        landscape: { 
            changePoint:640,
            visibleItems: 2,
            itemsToScroll: 2
        },

    loaded: function(object) {
        console.log('Slider loaded...');
    },
    before: function(object){
        console.log('Before transition...');
    },
    after: function(object) {
        console.log('After transition...');
    }
    });   

  </script>
```

Any help on how to implement this please??? And dont forget there is a js scripts and some css that goes in the head of the document.

Any help on how to implement this..
Cheers
**Michelle**

Comment: F12, what's in the console?

Comment: Sorry @mkaatman: i dont understand what you mean console?

Comment: Your browser has a built in development tool called the Javascript console. You can bring it up by hitting the F12 key on your keyboard or `Control+Shift+I`. It will tell you the exact errors that are happening. Developing without it is like trying to hit a nail using a hammer while wearing a blindfold while on fire.

Comment: did all that, saw the concol, no error shown, just a blank page att he bottom of the browser...

Comment: @mkaatman: this is what i got..SyntaxError: missing } after function body

Comment: Well, that tells you that there is a `});` missing at the end if your script (closing the `$(window).load()`-function).

Comment: @mkaatman: no luck. how will you fix it? can you help? please??? the slide works well when its saved as an html file. the propblem is only as a php file, there must be a way of echoing the scripts in php right?

Comment: @cars10 comment is correct. You are missing your 2nd `});` at the very end. (Just like the console says)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys.. I figured it out. What i did is took out the java script and save it as a js file, then link it in the head of my documents.